# undefined local variable or method `sign_out'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I get the following error when I click on the sign out link even though the method seems to be there.

```
NameError in SessionsController#destroy 
undefined local variable or method `sign_out' for #<SessionsController:0x007f87c8ecd8d8>
```

Here is my code,
Sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
     user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
     else
         flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
        render 'new'
     end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
   redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Sessions helper

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)

    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user

    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])

  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

   def sign_out
     self.current_user = nil
     cookies.delete(:remember_token)end
end
```

Layout

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the session helper in your session controller.

```rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper 
  ...
end
```

If you want to make session helper methods available in all controllers, add it in application controller instead of session controller.

Comment: I applogize, there was a minor typo in the session controller. It worked now